# bottom tool bar border not matching the height of the toolbar android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my buttons to fit within the border of the bottom toolbar. Right now my bottom toolbar looks like this. 
[image]

and the following xml files for the bottom toolbar.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeIcon"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calendarIcon"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_alt" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/heartIcon"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
            android:background="@drawable/oval_84" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/userIcon"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/user" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/group" />
```

the floating action button is intended to protrude out of the toolbar however the rest of my icons should be within the border. I used this drawable resource to set my border.

white_grey_border xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp">

<item
    android:bottom="-1dp"
    android:right="-1dp"
    android:left="-1dp"
    android:top="11dp">


<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="@color/colorGrey"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
</shape>

</item>
```

Previously my buttons were within the toolbar and linear layout height, but after adding the border it doesnt fit the toolbar's height and hence why the grey icons protrusion. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `BottomNavigationView`?

Comment: i wanted to customize the spacing of each icon because i want the floating action button to protrude out of the border and therefore a larger gap between the calendar and heart icon. I wasnt sure how to do that using bottom nav view since they entail equal spacing between icons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a component "View" instead of drawable background with "1dp" height.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <Toolbar />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I think bottom tool bar border not matching the height of the toolbar, because u set layout_height="1dp" for your drawable-layout and it's override "layout_height" of toolbar component.

p.s. u need to use bottom-navigation component instead of toolbar

Comment: Hi sorry could you post the whole code for this >< i dont seem to follow you , you are saying that my toolbar should be  the child of my linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

Oops i think i resolved it already i can just change the top in white grey border xml from 11dp to 1 dp or sth . Thanks for the answers.